# Hot Module Replace for Node Web Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

So, I've got Webpack and React running with HMR. Works real good, bar some of the gotchas.

In order to speed up development, I'm adding basic APIs written in JavaScript to the Express web server that is serving up the React HMR.

I would have thought this maybe very very very difficult (airing on impossible).. but is it possible to have the web server restart and reload all the API files (and potentially reconnect with the tab opened previously) when some backend APIs are changed??

Current express configuration:

```
import express from 'express';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import config from '../webpack.config.dev';
import open from 'open';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import session from 'express-session';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

import clientApi from '../backend/client.api';
import sessionApi from '../backend/session.api';
import profileApi from '../backend/profile.api';
import * as loginApi from '../backend/login.api';
import IdentityService from '../backend/identity-service';
/* eslint-disable no-console */

const port = 5003;
const app = express();
const compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parsing application/json
app.use(cookieParser()); // parsing cookies

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy 

app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../src/login.html'));
});

loginApi.configureUnsecure(app);

app.get(/^\/(?!api).*$/i, function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, '../src/index.html'));
});

const identityService = new IdentityService();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    let authenticated = identityService.checkAuthentication(req);

    if (authenticated) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
});

clientApi(app);
sessionApi(app);
profileApi(app);
loginApi.configureSecure(app);

app.listen(port, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        open(`http://localhost:${port}`);
    }
});
```

Would you possibly run this from a Gulp task?

Like:

```
gulp.task('watch-backend', () => {
    gulp.watch('./backend/**/*.*', () => {
        // close down old server in node
        // spin up new server in node
    });
});
```

Not really sure what the comments would look like in code?!

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to use [`nodemon`](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) which will restart the Node process when a file changes, it's a direct replacement for the Node cli e.g.

```
$ nodemon server.js
```

However, if your APIs are mounted on the same express server as your Webpack assets you will find it to be very slow to restart because the Webpack compilation will re-run from cold.

You might therefore find it better to start up two servers on different ports, one for your Webpack assets and another for your Node API.

Comment: The whole point was to do it on one server, otherwise I would have written the APIs in C#. I'm definitely fine waiting, because the APIs are to provide experience and template for future C# implementation, they will actually be changed very rarely! I will definitely look into the nodemon approach, however I run `npm start -s` to initiate the dev server

Comment: @CallumLinington `npm start` will be defined in `package.json` so you could change it or even define another script such as `npm run start:dev` which uses the `nodemon` cli instead of `node`.